# Trying to display multiple records from a single database in symfony 2

Tags: doctrine, symfony, twig

In the project I'm working on, I need to display 5 of the latest news articles on the website. In the Controller, I have written the following code:

```
      $news = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
          ->Where('p.contenttype = :type')
          ->setParameter('type', 'newsarticle')
          ->orderBy('p.lastedit', 'ASC')
          ->getQuery();

      $latestnews = $news->getResult();
```

This doesn't work for some reason, as I get the error message:

> Item "url" for "Array" does not exist in "ShoutMainBundle:Default:page.html.twig" at line 34

However, when I change the `getResult();` to `getSingleResult();` it works, but will only display the one record (which is what I expect when I use that code).

This is where I come unstuck and confused about what I'm supposed to be doing. I have googled "how to display multiple records in symfony" and I haven't found the answer. (If the answer has been out there, I apologise in advance for this). In normal PHP, I would expect to do a foreach loop (something similar anyway) to get the results which I need. But I also have a feeling that to achieve what I want I need to do something in Twig. But what I need to do I don't know.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit:**
Here is the template code that is used to display this:

```
            <section id="latestnews">
            <h2>Latest News</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="..{{ news.url }}" title="Read {{ news.title }}" />{{ news.title }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

Comment: Please show the template code.

Comment: I've put the template code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code tries to read from the variable `news`, and assumes that this variable has fields `url` and `title`. If your controller returns an array, you have to tread `news` as an array and iterate over it.

```
<section id="latestnews">
  <h2>Latest News</h2>
  <ul>
  {% for news in latestnews %}
   <li><a href="..{{ news.url }}" title="Read {{ news.title }}" />{{ news.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I used your code but it still failed, but swapping "news" and "latestnews" around, and adding "latest" to all references of "news" fixed the problem, and now my news articles display. Many thanks!

Comment: Of course, you need to adjust the variable names - `{% for news in news %}` won't work ;)

Comment: Haha, I know now. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your template, you're looking for an object that's not found. It's looking for the url in an array object, but it doesn't exist. I think you need to put in a check, to see if that exists in the array, and then echo if it does. So something like if(news.url) echo news.url;

It may not be that exact syntax obviously, I'm not all that familiar with twig, but something similar to that.

Comment: It's confusing because the query itself works (as displayed when using getSingleRecord(), it's when getRecord() is used it complains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the "news" results array in Twig.

```
{% for n in news %}

    <li><a href="..{{ n.url }}" title="Read {{ n.title }}" />{{ n.title }}</a></li>

{% endfor %}
```